# What does this "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str" error mean?

Tags: python

So I'm learning python and I've tried to use this code to make an image duplicator for convenience so that I can replicate this image 5 (or any other number) times at once, but I keep getting this problem.

````
import shutil

src = r'D:\src\C:\Users\Gamal\Pictures\Picture21.jpg'
ext = r'.jpg'

#Change the 5 to what number you want to duplicate

for i in range(5):
shutil.copy(src, f'{src + (i) + ext}')```
````

Comment: Error says you can't add int to string, you should convert int to string using `str(number)` and that will do the trick

Comment: I attempted to compile it with the solution below  but encountered a permission problem. PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\\src\\C:\\Users\\Gamal\\Pictures\\Picture21.jpg

Comment: @HI Look closely at your `src` and fix it...

Answer (score 1):

It means you can't use `+` with `src` (a string) and `i` (an integer).

Use f-string interpolation as is and don't try to use `+` to "sum up" integers with strings:

```
for i in range(5):
   shutil.copy(src, f'{src}{i}{ext}')
```

Comment: I attempted to compile it but encountered a permission problem.                                              ```PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\\src\\C:\\Users\\Gamal\\Pictures\\Picture21.jpg```

Comment: Yes, well, if you look at that path, there's something quite wrong with it. ;-)

Comment: Sorry i don't follow, is it the "D:"?, if so i've tried changing that to "C:" but still get the same error.

Comment: No, it's not that. You just literally have two different drive letters in there – you probably mean either `D:\src` or `C:\Users\Gamal\Pictures\Picture21.jpg` but not both of them in the same path.

Comment: Besides, do you really want to concatenate your `src` plus a number plus your `ext`? It would result in files named `Picture21.jpg0.jpg`, `Picture21.jpg1.jpg`, `Picture21.jpg2.jpg`...

Comment: Ah yeah, I meant C:\Users\Gamal\Pictures\Picture21.jpg, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i is an integer but src is a string
you can't use + for two different types.